# Question on Scanner Methods - Multiple Tokens

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a question for the **new code line** in the following code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FahrenheitToCelsiusScanner{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a Fahrenheit value: ");
    int fahrenheit = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter a day of the week: ");  // ****new code line****
    String day = input.next();
    double celsius = (5.0/9) * (fahrenheit - 32);
    System.out.println(day + " Fahrenheit: " + fahrenheit);
    System.out.println(day + " Celsius: " + celsius);
  }
}
```

If I entered `78 Friday` after the first prompt, it gave me the following result where `Fahrenheit: 78` is on the same line as the second prompt.

```
Enter a Fahrenheit value: 78 Friday
Enter a day of the week: Friday Fahrenheit: 78
Friday Celsius: 25.555555555555557
```

In contrast, if I remove **new code line** and enter `78 Friday` after the first prompt, I would get the nicely formatted result:

```
Enter a Fahrenheit value: 78 Friday
Friday Fahrenheit: 78
Friday Celsius: 25.555555555555557
```

So.. what exactly does that line of code do? And what exactly adds a new line in the output? (Is it simply the "Enter" key that moves the cursor in the Mac Terminal and nothing related to the `\n` entered as an input?)

Answer (score 0):

You have created scanner object with InputStream where

```
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

> Scanner will read the input from InputStream into tokens (default
> delimiter is space in words).

In your case when you enterred '78 Friday[*Click Enter*]' here stream is split into two tokens.

- 78
- Friday

So your code won't stop at below code to input day of week.
It will scan  **78** by method `input.nextInt()` and immediately print "Enter a day of the week: " in the output and scan the next input **Friday** present in stream by method `input.next()`

I suggest to first input 78[*Click Enter*] then you will get second prompt then enter Friday [*Click Enter*].

Don't enter '78 Firday' at once

[Sample execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QEDk.png)